# Как составить сложную формулу получении коэффициента в зависимости от значения в столбце?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Не могу составить работающую формулу в excel по следующим условиям (m - значение в ячейке столбца M, k - коэффициент, который зависит от значения m):

если m>=1 и m<4, тогда k=1

если m=4, тогда k=0,85

если m=5, тогда k=0,6

если m=6 или m=7, тогда k=0,5

если m=8 или m=9, тогда k=0,3

если m=10, тогда k=0,2

если m>=11 и m<=15, тогда k=0,1

если m>=16 и m<=20, тогда k=0,05

иначе k=0

В целом задача состоит именно в получении коэффициента k в зависимости от значения в столбце m.
Возможно ли его рассчитать одной формулой? Или нужны какие-то промежуточные расчеты?

Comment: 1. можно увидеть ваши попытки решения? 2. m - целые или дробные числа? 3. какая версия Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в столбце `M` целые числа, то поможет простая `ВПР` с массивом констант:

```
=ВПР(M2;{0;0:1;1:4;0,85:5;0,6:6;0,5:8;0,3:10;0,2:11;0,1:16;0,05:21;0};2)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Даже у такого чайника, как я, получилось! Ура-ура!

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли его рассчитать одной формулой?

Я бы использовал [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) ... и работает быстрее чем If

Comment: `Select Case`  - явно не формула

Comment: Согласен - я бы функцию написал - она тут просится ...